# 230v GFCI spa with 115v spur

Tags: wiring, gfci, outdoor, hot-tub

Currently I have:

1. Main breaker panel
2. Conduit to outdoor socket, GFCI protected
3. Onwards connection to next outdoor socket

I'm having a hot tub, currently 115v plugged into the GFCI socket, upgraded to 230v (new 230v pump, existing dual voltage controller/heater). The 115v GFCI socket will be replaced by a 230v GFCI disconnect for spas, with new 6awg 4-wire wiring to the breaker box.

I ordered a 115v spur breaker which (if I understand correctly) will be inside the GFCI disconnect as an optional extra. **Can I use that spur to run to the next outdoor socket (#3 above)**?

Pump is 10A, heater 22A, GFCI disconnect max 50A.

I know the hot tub has to be hard wired with a dedicated supply but I don't understand if that includes downstream. If not, that's fine, just more work to connect item #3 to a different outdoor circuit.

Side question: **how high off the ground does the GFCI disconnect need to be**? The current 115v one is only about 18". Distance wise it's about 6ft from the hot tub, line of sight.

It will be inspected; just want to get it right rather than need a repeat inspection.

Comment: What make and model is your "spa box" GFCI disconnect?

Comment: It's listed on Spa Depot (from where I ordered it) as "MW 240V Spa GFCI Box / Disconnect - Up to 50A Load" https://www.spadepot.com/MW-Spa-GFCI-Load-CenterDisconnect-240V-up-to-50A-P10588C193.aspx

Comment: There's no need to put GFCIs on GFCIs, [unless your name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huVSl.png) is XZibit.  If the hot tub GFCI breaker protects the other breakers in the hot tub subpanel, a plain breaker and plain socket will do.  Just put a sticker on it saying "GFCI Protected".

Comment: My mistake. It's a 15A *breaker*, not GFCI. I'm aware that chained GFCIs are a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1):

### Yeah, this is just a 4-space NEMA 3R breaker panel with a GFCI breaker fitted for you

There really isn't much special about "spa panels" like yours; they're just small, outdoor rated, main lug breaker boxes with a GFCI breaker already fitted in them. So, you could fit a 15A breaker (or even a 15A GFCI breaker, as your panel is a Midwest Electric unit, which means it accepts GE THQL breakers) in one of the spare slots and run your outdoor socket(s) off of that, or even have *two* outdoor socket circuits on two separate 15A breakers!  And since the hot tub's on its own breaker in the spa panel, none of what you do with the extra slots will impact it provided you don't overload the feeder itself.

Comment: Thanks. "Spa disconnect/panel" is just the terminology they use for the setup rather than the device itself, I guess. That 10A+22A is everything on max anyway (heater+jet blast), so even with the downstream sockets using 15A (unlikely), that's still under the max rating.